# modal is not opening and not showing any error (all divs are closed)

Tags: php, html

Edited to include proper format for more readable and understandable code. Also fixed to where the proper placement for ideal performance with the Javascript files are added to the ending of the `<html>` tag opposed to the `<head>` tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>ROWLANDS SHOP</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-
         scalable=no">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="modal fade details-1" id="details-modal" tabindex="-1" 
         role="dialog" aria-labelledby="details-1" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                  <button class="close" type="button" onclick="closeModal()" 
                     aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" class="text-center"><?= 
                     $product['title'];?></h4>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                           <div class="center-block"></div>
                           <img src="<?= $product['image'];?>" alt="<?
                              =$product['title'];?>" class="details img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                           <h4>Details</h4>
                           <p><?= $product['description'];?></p>
                           <hr>
                           <p>price: $<?= $product['price'];?></p>
                           <p>Brand:<?= $brand['brand']; ?></p>
                           <form action="add_cart.php" method="post">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                 <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <label for="quantity">Quaantity:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" 
                                       name="quantity">
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="size">Size:</label>
                                 <select name="size" id="size" class="form-control">
                                 </select>
                                 <option vaue=""></option>
                                 <?php foreach($size_array as $string){
                                    $string_array = explode(':', $string);

                                    $size = $string_array[0];

                                    $quantity = $string_array[1];

                                    echo '<option 

                                    vaue="'.$size.'">'.$size.'('.$quantity' Avaliable)</option>';
                                    } ?>
                              </div>
                           </form>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" 
                     onclick="close_modal();">Close</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" 
                     class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"><span>Add to Cart</span></button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is other styles from Bootstrap Working? And could you please give more information such as where you are including the Javascript and Popper.js? I'm sorry but there is so much little information that is given that it could simply just be it's not loading Bootstrap into the project. Please revise and add some more information that can possibly help us debug this for you.

Here is the boilerplate for a modal in bootstrap and a trigger with a button. Take this and see if this works for you and then you can re-add the other components you had to it. If this doesn't open up a modal then it might just be a loading problem with Bootstrap.js.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the link to the official Bootstrap Documentation. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/

Also Please note that the code you have provided is missing the required Popper.js file. Please Add this code above the ending `<html>` tag.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If you simply don't want to use the online versions of the Bootstrap.js, Jquery.js, or Popper.js Here are the websites where you can find them and download them to easily extract to your project.

Jquery Code Uncompressed: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js - Just save this into a file called jquery.js and include it with a script tag

Bootstrap.js: Can be downloaded from the official Bootstrap Website - https://www.getbootstrap.com

Popper.js: https://popper.js.org/ - Can be downloaded here

Comment: The other bootstrap is working the javascript and js are included in my header page                  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>ROWLANDS SHOP</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

Comment: Include your Jquery.js, Bootstrap.js, And Popper.js down before the end of the html tag. You want those to run after the elements on the page has loaded. Please refer to this question that has already been answered on where to put them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488298/where-in-the-html-file-should-jquery-and-bootstrap-be-placed @SamuelOguocha If this helped please approve my answer and upvote it please :)